# I don not know how to handle user roles in my rails app along with using cancancan gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to rails and I am trying to build an app which has user model with three roles: admin, member and visitor.
I have set up the app and installed cancancan and devise gems. Then, I added 'role' to the user model through migration which gives the user the "visitor" default role:

```
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :integer, default: 0
  end
end
```

Then, I set up cancan ability by defining the authorizations:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    alias_action :create, :read, :edit, :update, :destroy, to: :crud  # The first argument to `can` is the action you are giving the user
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all 
    elsif user.member?
      can :crud, Item, user_id = user.id 
    elsif user.visitor?
      can :read, all
    end  
  end

end
```

I thought that I might need to define the roles in for user to be able to check their authorizations later throughout the app:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  enum role: [:visitor, :member, :admin] 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :items

  def admin?(user)
    if user.role == 2
      return true
    end
  end

  def member?(user)
    if user == current_user
      user.role = 1
      return true
    end
  end   

  def visitor?(user)
    if user != current_user && user.role != 2
      user.role = 0 
      return true
    end 
  end

end
```

As I have not configured the app to let users choose their roles and there should be a single "admin", I set myself as the "admin" by changing my user role in the rails console (which was "visitor" by default). I used 'byebug' in my controller to see if my role has been modified to "admin"; however, it was still "visitor". Then I signed out and entered as another user and I was expecting to have a "member" role, but it was "visitor".
I am sure I have not defined roles in proper place and I could not manage to update them in order to have appropriate roles as a user signs in; I was expecting that everyone can be a visitor unless he/she signs up or signs in, and the user's role should change to "member" after authorisation completed. so there is not a link between user's roles, authentication and cancan at this stage.
I highly do appreciate any instructions to help me establish these connections. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`enum role: [:visitor, :member, :admin]` will already generate the interrogation methods `visitor?`, `member?` and `admin?`.

So all you really need is:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord 
  enum role: [:visitor, :member, :admin] 
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :items
end
```

You can then call `user.visitor?` to test if a user a visitor or call `user.role` to get the enum key (`"visitor"`).

Your `admin?`, `member?` and `visitor?` methods are completely broken for a few reasons:

- `user.role` does not return an integer. It returns the enum mapping as a string ("visitor", "member", "admin") thus the integer comparison will always be false and the method will always return false. Refer to the [docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.4.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).
- `current_user` is not available in models as they are not request aware. That's a helper method which is available in your controllers and views. If you write unit tests for this code you would discover that it raises a NoMethodError.

There are also a few more little bugs like:

```
can :crud, Item, user_id = user.id
```

Here you're actually assigning a local variable so this code is equivalent to:

```
can :crud, Item, user.id
```

You want to use colons:

```
can :crud, Item, user_id: user.id
# which is short-hand for
can :crud, Item, { :user_id => user.id }
```

> I was expecting that everyone can be a visitor unless he/she signs up or signs in, and the user's role should change to "member" after authorization completed.

That's a very unfounded expectation. If you want this logic you need to implement it through callbacks or by customizing the Devise controllers.

Devise does not actually have a guest user feature - although one can be added.

Comment: I would recommend you look for one of the many tutorials on CanCanCan and Rolify and look at the [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki) for instructions on setting up the guest user and do this one step at a time and write test as you're going along so that you know that your code actually works before going on.

Comment: Thanks max,  decided to run my role implementations through devise and if statements instead. Thanks for your time